# Flip points when flipping images in Python-OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I have images and points coordinates in a XML file.

I flipped images horizontally using `flipHorizontal = cv2.flip(originalImage, 1)`

Now I want also to flip points. For example in the original image I have point coordinates of the top right corner of a door `point = [x, y]` read from XML file.

I want this point in the same corner in the flipped image `flipHorizontal`.

How can I get this new coordinates `pointFlip = [xFlip, yFlip]`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand the question, you simply do:

```
new_x = width-x-1
new_y = y
```

where width is the width of the image.

Comment: It works also if I flip vertically? Just changing ```width``` to ```height``` and acting on ```y```?

Comment: more like new_x = width-x

Comment: Indecies start at 0. The -1, is to correct that.

Comment: It makes more sense if you write it like this: (width-1)-x